# Why am I getting an error in Kotlin? (if, else if, else)

Tags: kotlin

Why am I getting an error in Kotlin? Can you help me?

```
 var age = 15

    if (age > 0){
        if (0 < age < 3){
            println("Baby")
        } else if (3 < age < 12){
            println("Child")
        } else if (12 < age < 18){
            println("Teenager")
        } else if (18 < age < 30){
            println("Young")
        } else if (30 < age < 60){
            println("Middle age")
        } else if (age > 60){
            println("Old")
        }
    }
```

Language: Kotlin

Comment: Have you considered telling us what error you get? I can guess that it is probably a compile error, since that is not valid code. Have a read through [Kotlin docs for if](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#if-expression). You might also want to check out [Kotlin when](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) (same page actually)

Comment: This is not valid syntax: `0 < age < 3`. You need 2 tests: `0 < age && age < 3`.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: You also have some ages in there that don’t fit any of the conditions...3, 12, 18, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Marstran already answered the question in the comments.

> This is not valid syntax: `0 < age < 3`. You need 2 tests: `0 < age && age < 3`.

I'll add that you can do this nicely with [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression):

```
when {
    age in 0..3 -> println("Baby")
    age in 4..12 -> println("Child")
    age in 13..19 -> println("Teenager")
    age in 20..29 -> println("Young")
    age in 30..60 -> println("Middle age")
    age > 60 -> println("Old")
}
```

Although I object to 30 being considered middle-aged. ;-)